# Epsilon and Delta switches in the definition

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove or disprove the next sentence:
If f is a continuous function then for epsilon greater than 0 there is delta greater then 0 s.t for every x happens |x-a|<epsilon so |f(x)-f(a)|<delta. I am not sure how to approach this kind of question. Would be happy to get some help thank you in advance.

Comment: The epsilon and delta are just placeholders. Continuity really means "For any small positive number, another small positive number can be found so the inequalities are satisfied."

Comment: Incidentally you may missing "If $f$ is a continuous function **at $a$** then for **any** $\epsilon>0$ ..."

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @SeanRoberson can you please explain? Because from what I understand I already know that f is continuous at a but now I have to prove what I wrote up there given that f is continuous

Comment: It's just a trivial restatement of the definition. Again, $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ are just placeholders, variables whose name does not matter. What they represent is what matters. For example, if I write "for every $\heartsuit > 0$ there is $\clubsuit > 0$ such that $0<|x-a| < \clubsuit$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\heartsuit$", I'm saying that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$.

Comment: @IvoTerek OP's question is not so trivial. It's not that the usual names for epsilon and delta are merely switched. This question is about if we can switch epsilon and delta in the implication; that is, rather than stating that there exists an open interval in the domain that is mapped to a given interval in the image, it is stating that for every interval in the domain, there is an interval in the image. These statements are not the same, hence the goal of the exercise

Comment: @Lourenco You're right, I was hasty and thought it was the old question that people already asked thousands of times here. My knee-jerk reaction is that the claim is false (a continuous bijection with discontinuous inverse should do it).

Comment: @IvoTerek Could you give an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little nudge. 
So, you know that, at $a$, $f$ is continuous, that is, for every positive $\epsilon$, there is $\delta$ st $|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ and your asked if that implies that for every positive $\delta$ there is an $\epsilon$ such that the same implication holds. Let's see if that is the case. 
 Firstly, note that, if, for some $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$, then all $\delta'<\delta$ exist such that the implication holds. That is, let the set $\delta(\epsilon)=\{\delta>0:|x-a|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon\}$. If $\delta \in \delta(\epsilon)$, then every $\delta'<\delta \in \delta(\epsilon)$. Now what of the rest of them? Does continuity guarantee their existence as well? Can you carry on from here?

Comment: Hi thank you but from I understand the question doesn’t ask about “for every delta there is an epsilon…”

Comment: @ohad That's what you wrote, only with the epsilon and delta names switched